# How to handle Exception In SQL Procedure returning Resultset as table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing Snowflake Procedure and using SNOWSCRIPT SQL  here is sample code, what i am doing .I am passing SQL query as Input parameter to this procedure and trying to return the table as resultset  object, I am trying to handle sql query exception in this code block using exception handling . I am getting following error "SQL compilation error: error line 36 at position 4 Declared return type 'TABLE' is incompatible with actual return type 'SCALAR'"

I want to Handle error and return the handled error to caller of procedure.

My question is how do i handle this exception.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST_RESULTTEST_ERROR_AHANDING( pSelectSql VARCHAR(1000))
    
    RETURNS TABLE()
    
    LANGUAGE SQL
    
    AS
    
    $$
    
    BEGIN
    
    DECLARE
    
        
                                                                            
    
       SELECT_EXCEPTION  EXCEPTION (-20002, 'Select Query Exception Occured');   
      
                                                                              
        SelectQueryResultSet RESULTSET;
        
       Query_Select_Statement VARCHAR;                                                              
      
    BEGIN
    
      
      
      Query_Select_Statement:=pSelectSql;
      
      SelectQueryResultSet := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query_Select_Statement);
      
      RETURN TABLE(SelectQueryResultSet);
      
    END;
    
                                                                              
    EXCEPTION 
    
    
          
       
       WHEN STATEMENT_ERROR then
        RETURN OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('Error type', 'STATEMENT_ERROR',
                                'SQLCODE', sqlcode,
                                'SQLERRM', sqlerrm,
                                'SQLSTATE', sqlstate);  
    
    END;               

             

$$
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return tables from Snowflake stored procedures, what you can do is append the rows in with the delimited strings or variants with JSON(the max limit will be 16mb.
You can write a function which will return a Table data type, but a function in Snowflake cannot use Dynamic SQL.
when you have a Table as a return type then we need to specify the column and the data type.
Please find the example as follows.

```
create or replace function testing_func()
RETURNS TABLE(x number,y number)
language SQL
AS $$
  SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,4 

$$;
select * from table(testing_func());
```

Comment: this doesn't resolve my error;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, because Snowflake stored procedures written in SQL language can (FINALLY) return tables, but Snowflake's documentation is limited.

I'm guessing you were using a preview release of Snowflake Scripting back in March. It looks like @HimanshuKandpal responded before Snowflake Scripting became a general availability feature in the [Snowflake May 2022](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-05.html) release. I'm writing this in October 2022, and SPs written in Snowflake Scripting [can return a table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting.html#returning-tabular-data), but their scripting lacks TRY blocks. So it goes.

I really hate how janky the following is, and I would welcome others' suggestions, but here's a working SP that will execute a SQL string, returns a table with the results, and will raise...AN...error if the SQL it executed fails. It isn't QUITE right (it usually prefixes the error with `Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line # at position #:`), but it at least throws an error and doesn't complain about the return type.

And note that all of my code examples (surrounded by `$$` to allow for embedded `;` and the like) confirm with Snowflake's instructions on [how to use Snowflake Scripting in the classic web interface/SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html).

```
create or replace procedure snow_exec_sql_str(exec_sql_str varchar)
returns table()
language sql
execute as caller as
$$
declare
  res resultset;
begin
  res := (execute immediate :exec_sql_str);
  return table(res);
exception
  when other then
    raise;
end;
$$
;
```

Note that if you wanted to swallow the error itself and return the SQL error as a varchar column instead (I recommend AGAINST that), you could replace the exception block with this, as in this [Snowflake community answer](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-return-Exception-as-string-In-snowflake-SQL-Procedure-which-returns-Resultset-as-a-table).

```
exception
  when other then
    res := (SELECT :sqlcode || ' ' || :sqlerrm || ' ' || :sqlstate as change_error_to_str);
    return table(res);
end;
```

Here's some example calls of the SP. I think they should work in any database with >= 2 tables outside of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema.

````
-- will run if you select from information_schema.tables
call snow_exec_sql_str(select top 5 * from information_schema.tables_error);

-- will run if you remove the conditional case when Table_DN > 1...
call snow_exec_sql_str(
select 
  listagg(
    concat('SELECT ''', src.Table_Name, ''' as Table_Name_, ''', src.List_Column
      , ''' as List_Column_', case when Table_DN > 1 then ', 1 as Flag' else '' end, chr(10))
    ,'UNION ALL ' 
  ) within group (order by Table_DN) as SQL_Str
from (
  select c.Table_Name
    ,listagg(c.Column_Name, ', ') within group (order by c.Ordinal_Position) as List_Column
    ,dense_rank() over (order by c.Table_Name) as Table_DN
  from information_schema.columns c
  where c.Table_Schema not in ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
    -- and c.Table_Name IN ('YOUR_TABLE_01', 'YOUR_TABLE_02')
  group by 1
  qualify Table_DN <= 2 -- need Table_DN = 2 to cause the error
) src
);

-- will run if you remove distinct from the listagg()
call snow_exec_sql_str(
  select c.Table_Name
    ,listagg(distinct c.Column_Name, ', ') within group (order by c.Ordinal_Position) as List_Column
    ,dense_rank() over (order by c.Table_Name) as Table_DN
  from information_schema.columns c
  where c.Table_Schema not in ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
    -- and c.Table_Name IN ('YOUR_TABLE_01', 'YOUR_TABLE_02')
  group by 1
  qualify Table_DN <= 2
);
```
````